# Confusion regarding the exact function of `netstat -e`

Tags: command-line, netstat

I have been meaning to use this command `netstat -e` for a script. I earlier thought it gives the data count of bytes uploaded/downloaded during a particular session when it is connected to the network and the data is reset for every session/profile. That however, doesn't seem to be the case.

What does the command do exactly, i.e. what's it its data tabulating mechanism? Per-session or per-day or per-boot or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Unix/Linux

Man pages are your best friend in this instance...

http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/0/netstat/

http://www.e-reading.link/htmbook.php/orelly/networking/puis/ch17_05.htm

#### Windows

If you mean netstat for Windows check out this link...

[windows netstat info](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/network-administration-the-netstat-command.html)

Also, it is best to create a written record of the connections that are made over some period of time. The command can then be written

```
netstat -b 5 >> C:\connections.txt
```

Note that as written, this command will run with five-second intervals until stopped by entering `Ctrl+c`, which is a general command to exit. (Some reports say that this can be fairly CPU intensive so it may cause a slower, single-core machine to run sluggishly. It was not noticeable on my dual-core machine.)

From: [here](http://commandwindows.com/netstat.htm)

Comment: The part I am whole-heartedly interested in is when does netstat reset its tabulated values? per-session or per-profile or when? These questions were not answered by the man pages. Any other help?

Comment: I think it's per-session and provides an option to specify an interval parameter in seconds to record network stats for.

Comment: Also the command line options may differ depending on the linux distro, e.g. BSD style netstat may differ from netstat on Ubuntu/Fedora,

Answer (score 1):

@Akshay, as of my knowledge 'netstat -e' produces extended version of netstat output. The netstat -e output includes couple of extra columns 'user', 'I-node' for each connection.
FYI - This is tested on my unix machine which is running on CentOS 5.9

Comment: I wanted to ask in specific connection to Windows. Also, the part I am whole-heartedly interested in is when does netstat reset its tabulated values? per-session or per-profile or when?